# iOS Visible=false, event elements are visible on screen

Tags: ios, visibility, appium-ios

Appium: 1.13.0

Xcode: 10.2

iOS: 12.1

Device (Simulators): iPhone 6, iPhone X

I have native app and run it on ‘iPhone 6, X’ simulator. When I look through source code using **GUI Appium** or get XML using `page_source`.

Some of `XCUIElementTypeCell` and `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` have attribute `visible=false`, but all of them are displayed. This is only happening one page of the app, other pages work fine.

Concern about: How can I do typical actions with them?

How is it possible? What changes should Development team make to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "displayed"? Are you sure they are actually visible or they just exist and are invisible to the user?

Comment: by displayed I mean they are visible on screen but in xml `visible=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of iOS you can't click & tap an element if `visibility=false` is, so a work around is to use TouchAction using x, y. Code is written in `python`

```
    def touch_on_element(self, element):
       x_position = element.location['x'] + element.size['width'] / 2
       y_position = element.location['y'] + element.size['height'] / 2
       TouchAction(self.driver).tap(x=x_position, y=y_position).perform()
```

you can import `TouchAction` using

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
```